# Converting Input Tag to Camel Case at Runtime

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, yup

I am using React with Formik & Yup , currently I have a input field which is as f

```
<input
              type="fname"
              name="fname"
              onChange={handleChange}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              value={values.fname}
              className="form-control inp_text"
              id="fname"
            />
```

I have the Yup logic as

```
  fname: Yup.string()
    .required("First Name is a required field")
    .min(1, "Name is too Short")
    .max(20, "Name is too Big")
    .matches(
      /^[A-Z][A-Za-z]*( [A-Z][A-Za-z]*)*$/,
      "Not a correct format. Eg. Rahul Kumar "
    ),
```

which is working when I manually write it
but my requirement is that if I write at run time only it should covert to Camel case

for Example

abhimanu singh -> Abhimanu Singh
Abhi Raj -> Abhi Raj

Like this can anyone help me or guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the value to Camel Case before calling `handleChange` like:

```
const handleChangeWithCamelize = (e) => {
  const copyE = { ...e };
  copyE.target.value = camelize(copyE.target.value);
  handleChange(e);
};

<input
  id="fname"
  type="text"
  value={values.fname}
  onChange={handleChangeWithCamelize}
  onBlur={handleBlur}
  className={
    errors.fname && touched.fname
      ? "text-input error"
      : "text-input"
  }
/>
```

and camel case converter function will be like:

```
function camelize(text) {
  const words = text.split(" ");

  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (words[i] && words[i].length > 0) {
      words[i] = words[i][0].toUpperCase() + words[i].substr(1);
    }
  }

  return words.join(" ");
}
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/camel-case-converter-ikykel?file=/index.js) for a live working example.

Comment: See my answer for single line camelize function

Answer (score 0):

The `camelize` function @Ahmet Emre Kılınç posted can be simplified with a single regex:

```
function camelize(text) {
 return text.replace(/\b[a-z]/g, m => m.toUpperCase());
}
```